# jQuery: Delete rows from multiple tables simultaneously

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use dynamically generated rows for the form preview, and I'm trying to remove rows in two different tables simultaneously. We say if I delete the second line (#2) on "AddFieldsToFormDiv" I want that second line (#2) on "AddFieldsToPreviewDiv" removed simultaneously. Do you have workable solution ?

[Here's the js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/63umF/98/)

I tried to use:

```
$("#AddFieldsToFormDiv, #AddFieldsToPreviewDiv")
    .on("click", "#DeleteRowButton", function (event) 
    {
        $(this).closest("tr").remove();
        counter--;
    });
```

but without the result I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the main reason that this is only working for your AddFieldsToFormDiv table is because you are only doing any work on AddFieldsToFormDiv. This function you have here is binding a click element to both tables with #DeleteRowButton elements. The problem here is that AddFieldsToFormDiv is the only table with any of these #DeleteRowButton elements, so binding the click to the other table is completely pointless. Once we have that cleaned up, you still have to perform the remove on both tables. I modified your function for it to work.

```
$("#AddFieldsToFormDiv").on("click", "#DeleteRowButton",function (event) {
    var rowIdx = $(this).closest("tr").index();
    removeRowFromTable($("#AddFieldsToPreviewDiv"), rowIdx);
    removeRowFromTable($("#AddFieldsToFormDiv"), rowIdx);

    counter--;
});  

function removeRowFromTable( table,  rowIdx){
    table.find("tr").eq(rowIdx).remove();
}
```

Comment: Now I see my incorrect logical thinking. Thanks for the reply, it works perfectly.